# JS - Do I need to explicitly import JSDoc typedefs in VS Code to have intellisense support?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have a module

`camera.d.js`

that only contains the following definition:

```
/**
 * @typedef {object} CropperConfiguration
 * @property {Dimension} dimensions - Dimensions.
 */
```

and imports the module

`global.d.js`

that contains the following definition:

```
/**
 * @typedef {object} Dimension
 * @property {number} width - Width.
 * @property {number} height - Height.
 */
```

So... if `camera.d.js` imports `global.d.js`... in my module `CameraUtils.js`, that imports `camera.d.js`, do I need to import `global.d.js` to access the `Dimension` definition?

I thought that yes, but... for some reason I don't understand, I can perfectly access this definition only importing `camera.d.js` and ignoring `global.d.js`.

Why?

--

### Update

*Full content of `camera.d.js`*

```
/**
 * @file Camera type definitions.
 * @license MIT
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @since 1.0.0
 * @category utils
 * @subcategory camera
 * @module CameraTypes
 */

import "../global/global.d";

/**
 * @typedef {object} CropperConfiguration
 * @property {Dimension} dimensions - Dimensions.
 * @property {string} name - Cropper's vector icon name.
 * @property {string} type - Cropper's vector icon type.
 */
```

*And... for importing the types in `CameraUtils.js` I just do:*

```
import "./camera.d"; // global scope

...
```

Comment: Are these actual modules or are they scripts applying to the global scope? How does *camera.d.js* actually import *global.d.js* - it doesn't in the code you've shown? How do you import *camera.d.js* in the code where you try to refer to `Dimension`?

Comment: @Bergi, I updated the question

Comment: What is `@typedef`, what tool are you using for this? How do you "access" the definition?

Comment: @Bergi It's JSDoc, and he doesn't "access" it. VS Code or other IDEs use it for intellisense purposes, as well as it serves for generating the documentation.

Comment: `@typedef` from JSDoc. I "access" (intellisense) it in the documentation. I mean, vscode and the auto-generated docs detect it.

Comment: Your question depends on how VS Code internally works with JSDoc. I don't think anyone will be able to tell you how it works.

Comment: @connexo Yes, I know the syntax, but the exact tool matters. It might be vscode's javascript/typescript language server for autocompletion, it might be jsdoc itself that generates a documentation, it might be something else - and I'm not sure whether they all agree on scoping rules.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using JSDocs with VSCode IntelliSence for a few years now. By default, it's disabled, so you have to enable it first:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig

I have a public project you can reference from here:

https://github.com/clshortfuse/webhoster/blob/master/jsconfig.json

But basically, you need:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "checkJs": true,
  }
}
```

You don't need a`.d.js` file. You can inline them. You can also use a `.d.ts` file for complex types and then import the `.js` equivalent inline.

See: https://github.com/clshortfuse/webhoster/tree/master/types